# Android Can't Stop Sound When Clicking The Negative Dialog Button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm trying to display a dialog that let's the user pick from a list of different sounds like the beach, forest etc. When I test my app out and click ok in the dialog it does start playing the sound but when I click cancel it doesn't stop even though I stop the Media Player object with a click listener for the negative button you can see my full code below for my dialog fragment class. I don't know why the sound doesn't stop even though I've coded it to do so after clicking the negative button in the dialog.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import java.lang.IllegalStateException

class WhiteNoiseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var waves: MediaPlayer
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        waves = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.thai_wave)
        return activity?.let {
            // use builder to construct dialog
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder.setTitle(R.string.test_noise_dialog)
                .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.noise_array, -1,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    // TODO: Customize toast for different options
                     Toast.makeText(this, "You've Selected something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        waves.start()
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Starting Sound", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        waves.stop()
                        waves?.release()
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    })

            // create the dialog object and return it
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

Comment: Since clicking any of the `AlertDialog`'s buttons will dismiss the dialog, I'll assume that you're creating and showing `WhiteNoiseDialogFragment` a second time in order to click cancel. If so, that's likely the issue, since each time you do that, `waves` points to a different `MediaPlayer` player instance, and that second, new instance is not the one that's playing the audio from the first time when you clicked start. Follow me? If your `MediaPlayer` is meant to live longer than the dialog, then you might want to move it out of `WhiteNoiseDialogFragment`.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I get what you're saying and now understand that it's creating a new instance each time because onCreateDialog is being called each time as well on each button click that triggers the dialog. With making my MediaPlayer object live longer than the dialog I would think putting it in a companion object would be suitable but then I can't get the correct context. Do you know how I'd be able to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think I'd use a `companion object` for this. I'm not sure of your current setup or the desired design, but if that dialog really should be able to be closed while still playing the selected sound, then perhaps the parent `Activity`/`Fragment` should hold the `MediaPlayer`. Otherwise, if you'd rather that the dialog stay open while the user plays different sounds, then you'd keep the `MediaPlayer` in `WhiteNoiseDialogFragment`, but you'd have to modify the dialog code and behavior a bit.

Comment: @Mike thanks got it working by passing in the media players as arguments when creating a instance of the whitenoisedialog class in my activity.